# Парсером хочу извлечь текст из тега, но он извлекается с символами \t \n

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup

В HTML-коде (который я смотрю в DevTools, вкладка Элементы) в теге есть текст (одно слово). Когда я его извлекаю парсером, то в консоли редактора в тексте появляются неотображаемые символы:

> '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBelaria\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'

Откуда они взялись если в хтмл-коде их нету?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

my_url = 'https://en.nuevosedificios.es/api/widget/Projects/e25bdf6a?page=2'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                  ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
res = requests.get(my_url)  # res.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(repr(soup.find('div', class_='card__heading heading heading_type_h3 mr-2').text))

#  '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBelaria\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

[image: HTML-код и слева слово, как выглядит на веб-странице]

Comment: print(soup.find(class_='card__heading').text.strip())

Comment: Так вот же они в html-коде https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7RDL.png

Comment: @andreymal, не знал что отображаются только одним пробелом. В реальности то их много.